# Web2py Rating Widget (5 of them and in the same line)

Tags: database, widget, web2py, rating

I have a new problem.

I already done my widget but now i want 5 rating widget's for 5 categories in my database.

I have this column in my database (named places.categ):

```
places.categ
       a
       b
       c
       d
       a
       e
       ....
```

I have 21 markers in my Google Maps and each one of them as a category. (a,b,c,d or e).

How can i associate 5 rating widgets to those 21 markers by category? All i could do was this:

```
db.define_table('product',
Field('A', 'integer',requires=IS_IN_SET(range(1,6))), 
   Field('B', 'integer',requires=IS_IN_SET(range(1,6))),
   Field('C', 'integer',requires=IS_IN_SET(range(1,6))),
   Field('D', 'integer',requires=IS_IN_SET(range(1,6))),
   Field('E', 'integer',requires=IS_IN_SET(range(1,6))))
```

I have this code in my models/db.py and this one in my controllers/default.py:

```
from plugin_rating_widget import RatingWidget

# Inject the widgets
db.product.A.widget = RatingWidget()
db.product.B.widget = RatingWidget()
db.product.C.widget = RatingWidget()
db.product.D.widget = RatingWidget()
db.product.E.widget = RatingWidget()




# form2 = SQLFORM.factory(
   # Field('Rating','integer',widget=SQLFORM.widgets.RatingWidget))

   # if form2.process().accepted:
   #     print form2.vars.search



form2 = SQLFORM(db.product)
if form2.accepts(request.vars, session):
    session.flash = 'submitted %s' % form2.vars
    redirect(URL('index'))
```

I have 5 rating widget but they are not associated to my database and they are vertical (in 5 lines) and not in 1 line, like i wanted too.

TIA.

P.S.: I have the plugin rating widget uploaded.

Comment: Anyone? I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in another way. I get colors to each category with this code:

```
var amarelo = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png",
  new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
var vermelho = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
  new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
var verde = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png",
  new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
var azul = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png",
  new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
var branco = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png",
  new google.maps.Size(12, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
var sombra = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png",
  new google.maps.Size(22, 20),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(6, 20));
```

I awarded each category in one of this colors (example):

```
if (placescoordjs[i][4]== 'a')
    {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(placescoordjs[i][1],placescoordjs[i][2]),
        icon: amarelo, shadow: sombra,
        map: map,
        title: placescoordjs[i][3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(placescoordjs[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
     }
```

I have more 3 "else if" and the final else with the final color to my last category.

Thanks anyway. ;)